# Google Webmasters Tools - Accidentally changed something and quickly switched back

Tags: google-search-console, geotargeting

In Google Webmasters Tools I accidently changed Geotargeting to from *No Preference* to *United States*. I realized that was a mistake and changed it back within 2 minutes. Will changes take effect or will it be ignored because I changed switched it back so quickly?

I'm freaking out because I hope it doesn't destroy all of the indexing / SEO. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be ignored.  Google doesn't respond instantly to changes in GWT...you have to set something and leave it set that way and Google catches up on the next index pass.